# How to bind a variable in a snowflake create schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a simple sql code I want to execute in my stored procedure 
I am trying to bind the name of a schema but I am struggling to make it work 
Below is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATABASE.SCHEMA."CREATE_SCHEMA"("SCHNAME" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT='Creates roles for new schemas'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$

    var sqlCode = "CREATE SCHEMA ?";  
    var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:sqlCode,binds:[SCHNAME]});  
    var result_set = statement.execute(); 

$$
```

When I bind variables in a select query for example, it works but I don't know how to do it 
in a statement above like CREATE 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that binds are variables. When you use variables in Snowflake for object names, you need to use them inside the IDENTIFIER() function. The same rule applies for the SP:

```
var sqlCode = "CREATE SCHEMA identifier(?)";
```